# Formula for coefficients when n n-dimensional vectors are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

If you have $n$, $n$-dimensional vectors $\lbrace{\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,...,\vec{v}_n\rbrace} $ where each $\vec{v}_i$ is an $n$-dimensional vector, then these vectors are not generically linearly dependent. However, if the $n\times n$ matrix formed by taking its columns to be these vectors $M_i^j=v_i^j$, has a vanishing determinant $\text{Det}[M^j_i]=0$, then the vectors are linearly dependent, i.e., the following equation admits a non-trivial solution
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\vec{v}_i=0
\end{equation}

**Question:** Is there a general formula for a solution for the coefficients $\alpha_i$? i.e., when you have $n+1$, n-dimensional vectors, then Crammer's rule provides a nice solution for the $\alpha_i$'s, but in this circumstance, we have $n$, $n$-dimensional vectors, which we know are linearly dependent because of the vanishing determinant condition.

Comment: Yes. Use the fact that $A \text{ adj}(A) = \det(A) = 0$ in this case where $\text{adj}(A)$ is the adjugate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Comment: Could you explain further?

Comment: If $\det(A) = 0$ then each column of the adjugate produces a vector $v$ such that $Av = 0$. This is exactly a linear dependence among the columns of $A$.